# How to compile and execute from memory directly?

Tags: c++, linux

Is it possible to compile a C++ (or the like) program without generating the executable file but writing it and executing it directly from memory?

For example with `GCC` and `clang`, something that has a similar effect to:

```
c++ hello.cpp -o hello.x && ./hello.x $@ && rm -f hello.x
```

In the command line.

But without the burden of writing an executable to disk to immediately load/rerun it.

(If possible, the procedure may not use disk space or at least not space in the current directory which might be read-only).

Comment: @David Heffernan, alfC never explicitly specified using Linux. He just provided a `gcc` build process as an example of what he wanted to do.

Comment: @TJD Using a RAM disk to decrease build times is a fairly common idea. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442170/is-it-sensible-to-use-a-ramdisk-on-a-build-server) for example.

Comment: @slavik262 The question specifically mentions Linux. Anyway, any answer is going to be heavily OS specific.

Comment: @slavik262 Doesn't the OS disk cache remove the need for RAM disks?

Comment: @slavik262, Yes using RAM disk is great because it speeds the access to the various source and intermediate object files.  This question is just asking about the burden of writing the final executable, not putting the whole build tree in RAM.

Comment: Thank you all for the interest. If a compiler supported this, it would be a compiler-dependent question, but not necessarily a OS dependent question. I'll remove the Linux reference (just and example) if that is confusing. Also, thank you for the RAM disk suggestions. My motivation is not for speeding up compilation (optimization) necessarily, but to be able to compile and run in situations where write-to-disk (globally or locally) is not guaranteed although the sources are available; so I was looking for a compiler/tool-based solution.

Comment: Also, let me clarify that although closely related, and similar in effect, this question is not about a C++ interpreter.

Comment: @TJD, no, I don't want this for optimization particularly.

Comment: @alfC What do you mean with _'Lothar Krause's answer seems to be in the right direction but it doesn't have enough detail'_? You didn't at least put any comment on this answer to tell what you're actually missing. IMHO Lothar Krause's answer clearly explains the solution. How to setup a pipe and using the executed command's results via a file handle is a completely different question. You should try to search for a sample for usage of `pipe()` and `fexecve()` or read the documentation.

Comment: I guess you put in words what I see missing (in part because of ignorance), "How to setup a pipe and using the executed command's results via a file handle"? Also file descriptor is something I didn't know about. In my ignorance it looked that his answer was just a proof of concept not a complete answer, but probably I am missing something.

Comment: @alfC You wrote that write-to-disk (globally or locally) is not guranteed but in your question you state that it was possible to use temporary files. So do we have no gurantees for the temporary files either?

Comment: @LotharKrause, I mean that if the compiler needs to write temporary files and finds the location to do it then is fine. But maybe that is confusing. I'll remove it from the question.

Comment: I don't understand why writing to some fast file system (`tmpfs` or on a fast disk, e.g. SSD) is not enough: most of the time is spent in compiling that C++ generated code, so IO time is negligible.

Comment: You should explain why you don't want to go thru files. I don't understand why you want to avoid files. (Performance or time is not relevant; most of the time is spent inside `g++` once you have `-O` or `-O2` ....)

Comment: I know you are probably interested in methods that will work with current tools, but historically the answer is absolutely yes.  The method is called "compile and go." It is discussed in older compiler textoobks and has been around since at least the 60's. The idea was to eliminate file system delays, and it worked well.  E.g. from mid-80's to mid-90's there were several versions of Turbo Pascal that did this.  They were blazingly fast: 10's of thousands of lines per second on the 80486 processors of the day, when file-based compilation schemes were doing thousands or hundreds.

Comment: Compile and go from the 1960s is quite similar to today's Just In Time compilation

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, for example suppose I want to compile/execute without relying in having a writable space. Or avoid intermediate files.

Answer (score 52):

Possible? Not the way you seem to wish. The task has two parts:

### 1) How to get the binary into memory

When we specify `/dev/stdout` as output file in Linux we can then pipe into our program `x0` that reads
an executable from stdin and executes it:

```
  gcc -pipe YourFiles1.cpp YourFile2.cpp -o/dev/stdout -Wall | ./x0
```

In `x0` we can just read from stdin until reaching the end of the file:

```
int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    const int stdin = 0;
    size_t ntotal = 0;
    char * buf = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        /* increasing buffer size dynamically since we do not know how many bytes to read */
        buf = (char*)realloc(buf, ntotal+4096*sizeof(char));
        int nread = read(stdin, buf+ntotal, 4096); 
        if (nread<0) break;
        ntotal += nread;
    }
    memexec(buf, ntotal, argv); 
}
```

It would also be possible for `x0` directly execute the compiler and read the output. This question has been answered here: [Redirecting exec output to a buffer or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file)

*Caveat:* I just figured out that for some strange reason this does not work when I use pipe `|` but works when I use the `x0 < foo`.

*Note:* If you are willing to modify your compiler or you do JIT like LLVM, clang and other frameworks you could directly generate executable code. However for the rest of this discussion I assume you want to use an existing compiler.

### Note: Execution via temporary file

Other programs such as UPX achieve a similar behavior by executing a temporary file, this is easier and more portable than the approach outlined below. On systems where `/tmp` is mapped to a RAM disk for example typical servers, the temporary file will be memory based anyway.

```
#include<cstring> // size_t
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h> // perror
#include <stdlib.h> // mkostemp
#include <sys/stat.h> // O_WRONLY
#include <unistd.h> // read
int memexec(void * exe, size_t exe_size, const char * argv)
{
    /* random temporary file name in /tmp */
    char name[15] = "/tmp/fooXXXXXX"; 
    /* creates temporary file, returns writeable file descriptor */
    int fd_wr = mkostemp(name,  O_WRONLY);
    /* makes file executable and readonly */
    chmod(name, S_IRUSR | S_IXUSR);
    /* creates read-only file descriptor before deleting the file */
    int fd_ro = open(name, O_RDONLY);
    /* removes file from file system, kernel buffers content in memory until all fd closed */
    unlink(name);
    /* writes executable to file */
    write(fd_wr, exe, exe_size);
    /* fexecve will not work as long as there in a open writeable file descriptor */
    close(fd_wr);
    char *const newenviron[] = { NULL };
    /* -fpermissive */
    fexecve(fd_ro, argv, newenviron);
    perror("failed");
}
```

*Caveat:* Error handling is left out for clarities sake. Includes for sake of brevity.

*Note:* By combining step `main()` and `memexec()` into a single function and using `splice(2)` for copying directly between `stdin` and `fd_wr` the program could be significantly optimized.

### 2) Execution directly from memory

One does not simply load and execute an [ELF](http://linux.die.net/man/5/elf) binary from memory. Some preparation, mostly related to dynamic linking, has to happen. There is a lot of material explaining the various steps of the ELF linking process and studying it makes me believe that *theoretically* possible. See for example this closely related [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911993/how-to-generate-and-run-native-code-dynamically) however there seems not to exist a working solution.

**Update** UserModeExec seems to come very close.

Writing a working implementation would be very time consuming, and surely raise some interesting questions in its own right.  I like to believe this is by design: for most applications it is strongly undesirable to (accidentially) execute its input data because it allows [code injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33340/Code-Injection-into-Running-Linux-Application).

What happens exactly when an ELF is executed? Normally the kernel receives a file name and then creates a process, loads and maps the different sections of the executable into memory, performs a lot of sanity checks and marks it as executable before passing control and a file name back to the run-time linker `ld-linux.so` (part of libc). The takes care of relocating functions, handling additional libraries, setting up global objects and jumping to the executables entry point. AIU this heavy lifting is done by `dl_main()` (implemented in libc/elf/rtld.c).

Even `fexecve` is implemented using a file in `/proc` and it is this need for a file name that leads us to reimplement parts of this linking process.

Libraries

- [UserModeExec](http://plash.beasts.org/wiki/UserModeExec)
- [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/) -- read, modify, create ELF files
- [eresi](http://www.eresi-project.org/) -- play with elfes
- [OSKit](http://www.cs.utah.edu/flux/oskit/) (seems like a dead project though)

Reading

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060?page=0,0 -- introduction
- http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF -- good overview
- http://s.eresi-project.org/inc/articles/elf-rtld.txt -- more detailed Linux-specific explanation
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33340/Code-Injection-into-Running-Linux-Application -- how to get to hello world
- http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/elf.html -- nice reference of ELF structure
- [Loaders and Linkers by John Levine](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) -- deeoer explanation of linking

Related Questions at SO

- [Linux user-space ELF loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784495/linux-user-space-elf-loader)
- [ELF Dynamic loader symbol lookup ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666248/elf-dynamic-loader-symbol-lookup-ordering)
- [load-time ELF relocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349120/load-time-elf-relocation)
- [How do global variables get initialized by the elf loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649333/how-do-global-variables-get-initialized-by-the-elf-loader)

So it seems possible, you decide whether is also practical.

Comment: ok, so I issued the first command and get the executable output (binary codes) to the screen. That looks promising, where do I pipe this to? Do I have to pipe it a special executable made from your C code? Where are `pipe`, `fork`, `exec` used? How the piped binary code is related to  `"fooXXXXX"?

Comment: You are right, maybe I made somewhat of a jump. The piped binary code will be written using the file descriptor `fd` which will have a random name starting with foo. Hope I can provide an example later. In any case my starting point would be this: http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~mia/tutorials/coen346/IPC_threads/pipe_parent_child.html

Comment: Awesome answer, first I wonder why something like your program is not one of the programs included in the operating system, that is a program that takes a binary stream and executes it. Second there it seems to be a problem with the `main` part of the code as the `./x0` hangs while reading a stream. I had to change to `if (nread != 0) break;` in order to finish reading the stream. And with this change I get a message `failed: Exec format error`. I am trying implementation 2) so far.

Comment: @alfC I assume it is loading the file. Unfortunately I am away from my computer. Try using a fixed size read on `char buf[SOME_BIG_NUMBER]`

Comment: @alfC: because as cool as this answer is, something like `x0` is the biggest security hole I've ever seen. Especially considering how easy it would be to hack. I don't want that thing on my system. Never. They need to be integrated into one process so `x0` doesn't exist. Otherwise, your security is screwed.

Comment: I don't feel this answer works without files, it just deploys standard tricks about temporary files. I don't see the gain w.r.t. to using files (e.g. in a `tmpfs` system).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes, it seems that option 1 still relies in creating a temporary files and it is equivalent to use the `mktemp` program. Option 2 seems more promising but I can not make it work (as the `main` part doesn't work for me).

Answer (score 24):

Yes, though doing it properly requires designing significant parts of the compiler with this in mind. The LLVM guys have done this, first with a kinda-separate JIT, and later with the [MC](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/intro-to-llvm-mc-project.html) subproject. I don't think there's a ready-made tool doing it. But in principle, it's just a matter of linking to clang and llvm, passing the source to clang, and passing the IR it creates to MCJIT. Maybe a demo does this (I vaguely recall a basic C interpreter that worked like this, though I think it was based on the legacy JIT).

Edit: Found the [demo](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/clang-interpreter/) I recalled. Also, there's [cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling), which seems to do basically what I described, but better.

Comment: Although not a solution and I wasn't looking for an interpreter, this is the kind of answer I was expecting. +1

Comment: @alfC - You can do exactly what you want with LLVM JIT.  Create an llvm::Module from LLVM IR code (get it by compiling your C/C++ code into LLVM IR via clang linked into your executable).  Create an llvm::ExecutionEngine from that Module, and then call yourEngine->FindFunctionNamed(someFunction), and then yourEngine->runFunction(pSomeFunction) via JIT.  It can even give you a return value.  As long as you don't blow away your ExecutionEngine, the JITed code  can be called again & again, faster on subsequent calls because it's JITed on the 1st call.

Comment: as far as I know there is gcc JIT project and Android NDk-compatible ones. The problem is that its all implementation and os specific

Answer (score 22):

Linux can create virtual file systems in RAM using [tempfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs). For example, I have my `tmp` directory set up in my file system table like so:

```
tmpfs       /tmp    tmpfs   nodev,nosuid    0   0
```

Using this, any files I put in `/tmp` are stored in my RAM.

Windows doesn't seem to have any "official" way of doing this, but has many [third-party options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software#Microsoft_Windows).

Without this "RAM disk" concept, you would likely have to heavily modify a compiler and linker to operate completely in memory.

Comment: Hear hear.  I believe this is sometimes known as a "RAM disk".

Comment: Actually, the modifications needed on Windows would be fairly small. Just pass `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` when creating the output file. This suppresses the flush to disk, keeping the file in cache. The documentation explicitly states that this may avoid a write if the file is deleted soon after, as is intended here.

Answer (score 9):

If you are not specifically tied to C++, you may also consider other JIT based solutions:

- in Common Lisp [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) is able to generate machine code on the fly
- you could use TinyCC and its `libtcc.a` which emits quickly poor (i.e. unoptimized) machine code  from C code in memory.
- consider also any JITing library, e.g. [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit.html), GNU [Lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [asmjit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/)
- of course emitting C++ code on some tmpfs and compiling it...

But if you want good machine code, you'll need it to be optimized, and that is not fast (so the time to write to a filesystem is negligible).

If you are tied to C++ generated code, you need a good C++ optimizing compiler (e.g. `g++` or `clang++`); they take significant time to compile C++ code to optimized binary, so you should generate to some file `foo.cc` (perhaps in a RAM file system like some `tmpfs`, but that would give a minor gain, since most of the time is spent inside `g++` or `clang++` optimization passes, not reading from disk), then compile that `foo.cc` to `foo.so` (using perhaps `make`, or at least forking `g++ -Wall -shared -O2 foo.cc -o foo.so`, perhaps with additional libraries). At last have your main program `dlopen` that generated `foo.so`. FWIW, [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) was doing exactly that, and on Linux workstation the [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program shows that a process can generate then [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) many hundred thousands of temporary plugins, each one being obtained by generating a temporary C file and compiling it. For C++ read the [C++ dlopen mini HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/).

<sup>Alternatively, generate a self-contained source program `foobar.cc`, compile it to an executable `foobarbin` e.g. with `g++ -O2 foobar.cc -o foobarbin` and execute with `execve` that `foobarbin` executable binary</sup>

When generating C++ code, you may want to avoid generating tiny C++ source files (e.g. a dozen lines only; if possible, generate C++ files of a few hundred lines at least; unless lots of `template` expansion happens thru extensive use of existing C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), where generating a small C++ function combining them makes sense). For instance, try if possible to put several generated C++ functions in the same generated C++ file (but avoid having very big generated C++ functions, e.g. 10KLOC in a single function; they take a lot of time to be compiled by GCC). You could consider, if relevant, to have only one single `#include` in that generated C++ file, and pre-compile that commonly included header.

[Jacques Pitrat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pitrat)'s book *Artificial Beings, the conscience of a conscious machine* (ISBN 9781848211018) explains in details why generating code at runtime is useful (in symbolic artificial intelligence systems like his CAIA system). The [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project is trying to follow that idea and generate some C++ code (and hopefully, more and more of it) at runtime. [**Partial evaluation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) is a relevant concept.

Your software is likely to spend more CPU time in generating C++ code than [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) in compiling it.

Answer (score 3):

tcc compiler "-run" option allows for exactly this, compile into memory, run there and finally discard the compiled stuff. No filesystem space needed. "tcc -run" can be used in shebang to allow for C script, from tcc man page:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tcc -run
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

[C scripts](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&p=1913980#p1912584) allow for mixed bash/C scripts, with "tcc -run" not needing any temporary space:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foo"
sed -n "/^\/\*\*$/,\$p" $0 | tcc -run -

exit
/**
*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("bar\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Execution output:

```
$ ./shtcc2
foo
bar
$
```

C scripts with gcc are possible as well, but need temporary space like others mentioned to store executable. This script produces same output as the previous one:

```
#!/bin/bash

exc=/tmp/`basename $0`
if [ $0 -nt $exc ]; then sed -n "/^\/\*\*$/,\$p" $0 | gcc -x c - -o $exc; fi

echo "foo"
$exc

exit
/**
*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("bar\n");
    return 0;
}
```

C scripts with suffix ".c" are nice, [headtail.c](https://gist.github.com/Hermann-SW2/209918befa911209e06c5812e438dc37) was my first ".c" file that needed to be executable:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7" | ./headtail.c 
1
2
3
6
7
$
```

I like C scripts, because you just have one file, you can easily move around, and changes in bash or C part require no further action, they just work on next execution.

P.S:
The above shown "tcc -run" C script has a problem, C script stdin is not available for executed C code. Reason was that I passed extracted C code via pipe to "tcc -run". New gist [run_from_memory_stdin.c](https://gist.github.com/Hermann-SW/7bc1a49b90adabed45f5775b15139c5f) does it correctly:

```
...
echo "foo"
tcc -run <(sed -n "/^\/\*\*$/,\$p" $0) 42
...
```

"foo" is printed by bash part, "bar 42" from C part (42 is passed argv[⁠1]), and piped script input gets printed from C code then:

```
$ route -n | ./run_from_memory_stdin.c 
foo
bar 42
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.29.58.98    0.0.0.0         UG    306    0        0 wlan1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
172.29.58.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     306    0        0 wlan1
$
```

Comment: Very good.  Can it work for C++?

Comment: tcc is "Tiny C compiler", cannot deal with C++. I created g++ based [C++ script](https://gist.github.com/Hermann-SW/0d00f9afe0c274414220ee73e3a77120), where bash part outputs "hello " and C++ part outputs "world" (since g++ has no "-run" option, C++ executable is created under "/tmp" and executed from there).

Comment: Now works for C++ as well, see [C++ script section](https://github.com/Hermann-SW/memrun/tree/master/C#c-script-1) of my memrun C repo.

Answer (score 1):

One can easily modify the compiler itself. It sounds hard first but thinking about it, it seams obvious. So modifying the compiler sources directly expose a library and make it a shared library should not take that much of afford (depending on the actual implementation).

Just replace every file access with a solution of a memory mapped file.

It is something I am about to do with compiling something transparently in the background to op codes and execute those from within Java.

-

But thinking about your original question it seams you want to speed up compilation and your edit and run cycle. First of all get a SSD-Disk you get almost memory speed (use a PCI version) and lets say its C we are talking about. C does this linking step resulting in very complex operations that are likely to take more time than reading and writing from / to disk. So just put everything on SSD and live with the lag.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I am using SSD already, but that is not the only point. As you said the compiler could behave like and interpreter and execute just after compilation without creating files here and there.

Comment: Well if my try for the ASM in Java would work, someone might do the same with C. Would be nice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481317/inline-asm-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Finally the answer to OP question is yes!

I found memrun repo from guitmz, that demoed running (x86_64) ELF from memory, with golang and assembler. I forked that, and provided C version of memrun, that runs ELF binaries (verified on x86_64 and armv7l), either from standard input, or via first argument process substitution. The repo contains demos and documentation (memrun.c is 47 lines of code only):
https://github.com/Hermann-SW/memrun/tree/master/C#memrun

Here is simplest example, with "-o /dev/fd/1" gcc compiled ELF gets sent to stdout, and piped to memrun, which executes it:

```
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ gcc info.c -o /dev/fd/1 | ./memrun
My process ID : 20043
argv[0] : ./memrun
no argv[1]
evecve --> /usr/bin/ls -l /proc/20043/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Sep 18 22:27 0 -> 'pipe:[1601148]'
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Sep 18 22:27 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Sep 18 22:27 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Sep 18 22:27 3 -> /proc/20043/fd
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $
```

The reason I was interested in this topic was usage in "C script"s. run_from_memory_stdin.c demonstrates all together:

```
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ wc memrun.c | ./run_from_memory_stdin.c 
foo
bar 42
  47  141 1005 memrun.c
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $
```

The C script producing shown output is so small ...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foo"
./memrun <(gcc -o /dev/fd/1 -x c <(sed -n "/^\/\*\*$/,\$p" $0)) 42

exit
/**
*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("bar %s\n", argc>1 ? argv[1] : "(undef)");

  for(int c=getchar(); EOF!=c; c=getchar())  { putchar(c); }

  return 0;
}
```

P.S:
I added tcc's "-run" option to gcc and g++, for details see:
https://github.com/Hermann-SW/memrun/tree/master/C#adding-tcc--run-option-to-gcc-and-g

Just nice, and nothing gets stored in filesystem:

```
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ uname -a | g++ -O3 -Wall -run demo.cpp 42
bar 42
Linux raspberrypi400 5.10.60-v7l+ #1449 SMP Wed Aug 25 15:00:44 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $
```

Comment: When I run this command `g++ script.cpp -o /dev/fd/1 | ./memrun` I get `/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Illegal seek`

Comment: Please show output of "head -1 /etc/os-release" and "uname -a".
And "g++ --version".

Comment: `$ head -1 /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.10"` //
`$ uname -a
Linux cuk 6.5.0-13-generic #13-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Nov  3 12:16:05 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` // `$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0`